# Creating Contingency Solution Output File for PSS/E using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python to interact with PSS/E (siemens software) and I'm trying to create *.acc file for pss/e, from python. I can do this easily using pss/e itself:

1 - create *.sub, *.mon, *.con files

2 - create respective *.dfx file

3 - and finally create *.acc file

The idea is to perform all these 3 tasks automatically, using python. So, using the record tool from pss/e I get this code:

psspy.bsys(0,0,[ 230., 230.],1,[1],0,[],0,[],0,[])

psspy.bsys(0,0,[ 230., 230.],1,[1],0,[],0,[],0,[])

psspy.dfax([1,1],r"""PATH\reports.sub""",r"""PATH\reports.mon""",r"""PATH\reports.con""",r"""PATH\reports.dfx""")

psspy.accc_with_dsp_3( 0.5,[0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,0],r"""IEEE""",r"""PATH\reports.dfx""",r"""PATH\reports.acc""","","","")

psspy.accc_single_run_report_4([1,1,2,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,6000],[ 0.5, 5.0, 100.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 99999.],r"""PATH\reports.acc""")

It happens that when I run this code on python, the *.sub, *.mon, *.con and *.dfx files are not created thus the API accc_single_run_report_4() reports an error. Can anyone tell me why these files aren't being created with this code?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Magalhaes, the auxiliary files *.sub, *.mon and *.con are input files.  You have to write them; PSSE doesn't generate them.  Your recording shows that you defined a bus subsystem twice, generated a *.dfx from existing auxiliary files, ran an AC contingency solution, then generated an *.acc report.  So when you did this recording, you must have started with already existing auxiliary files.